# How to share login between two servers? Using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using the same database, both servers was on AWS and using the same domain.

Application One, was using PHP 5.6
Application Two, was using Laravel

I have some pages in App1 and anothers pages in App2,

How can I share the login credencials beetween this pages?

Thanks

Comment: _...I'm using the same database..._ Well, I think you already have answered your own question, right?

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.6 is beyond end of life and hasn't had a security update in a year and a half. Upgrade to a supported version of PHP.

Comment: "Application One, was using PHP 5.6 Application Two, was using Laravel" — You're comparing apples and oranges there.

Comment: Are you storing your session data in the db as well?

Comment: @Quentin I was migration all my page into Laravel, and i'm not comparing nothing, I was listing my server in this moment;

Comment: @CleanCode no man, I'm using session cookie, normally

Comment: @B001ᛦwell well :) I never use session directly on database, but i will see this way.. Thank U

Comment: _I never use session directly on database..._ I never talked about using session in databaes. Your question is getting more and more confusing. You were asking for sharing "the login credencials"....

Comment: do you mean SSO (Singe Sign ON)? if yes you can use https://github.com/jasny/sso. With SSO, logging into a single website will authenticate you for all affiliate site

Answer (score 0):

Some options/ideas you can do:

- Migrate all credentials into one central database. Take a look at OAuth to create Auth-Tokens, that you can use in your applications. This might be the easiest option.
- I guess what you want to do is like `When email + password is not found in App1, try to login into App2`. You could do a request from App 1 to App 2 via HTTPS/CURL and do a login request on App2. When this succeed, you can sync the data to App 1 and generate a session key there. Technically thats possible but it will give you more complexity and redundancy, I would not recommend go this way.
- Don't migrate, offer the user 2 Login possibilites in App 1. Login 1 for App 1 users. Login 2 would look similar to "Login with Facebook", "Login with GitHub" etc. When logging into App 1 with credentials from App 2, save a reference in App 1, like the unique ID but DON't sync the data. If you go this way I would also recommend to take a look at OAuth.

To answer better please provide more information in your question what exactly you plan to do.